# Union and intersection of Bohm trees

Tags: lambda-calculus

When I study the Bohm tree defined in *The Lambda Calculus: Its Syntax and Semantics, H.P. Barendregt, Elseviser*,$\cap\Phi$ or $\cup_i(M_i)$ always occurs. But I'm confused about the union and the intersection operation of Bohm trees. 
For example,
$A=\{<<>, \lambda x.x>, <<0>, \bot>, <<1>, x>\}$ and $B=\{<<>, \lambda x.x>, <<0>, x>, <<1>, x>, <<0,0>, x>\}$;
 $A=\{<<>, \lambda xy.x>, <<0>, \bot>, <<1>, x>\}$ and $B=\{<<>, \lambda x.x>, <<0>, y>, <<1>, \bot>\}$;
 $A=\{<<>, \lambda xy.x>, <<0>, \bot>, <<1>, x>\}$ and $B=\{<<>, \lambda x.x>, <<0>, \bot>, <<1>, y>\}$;
 $A=\{<<>, \lambda x.x>, <<0>, \bot>, <<1>, \bot>\}$ and $B=\{<<>, \lambda x.x>, <<0>, \bot>, <<1>, \bot>, <<2>, \bot>\}$.
What's the results after doing union or intersection $A$ and $B$?

Comment: I think the union or intersection operation only works on the case when two trees are consistent. So operation on the last two cases is meaningless.